# Which mood should I use in here?

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

> 1a) If he not lose the tomorrow's competition, he will be the champion. 
> 1b) If he win the tomorrow's competition, he will be the champion.

> 2a) If he does not lose the tomorrow's competition, he will be the champion.
>
> 2b) If he wins the tomorrow's competition, he will be the champion.

We don't know if he will loss or win the tomorrow's competition. So his loss is a hypothetical condition. Based on this, which one of the above sentences is grammatically correct (or preferred)?

I know that according to the conditional type 1, the second sentences (2a and 2b) are correct. But I think we say "he does not lose (wins) the tomorrow's competition" if we want to indicate a prediction base on our reasons or knowledge. But in here we want to express a hypothetical condition. Accordingly, I think the first sentences (1a and 1b) may be correct.

Comment: _Tomorrow's competition_ doesn't need an article. 1a and 1b are ungrammatical. If you want to make it _really_ hypothetical, you could say "If he were to win tomorrow's competition, he would be the champion."

Comment: Why doesn't Tomorrow's competition need an article?

Comment: It just doesn't! _The competition happening tomorrow_, but _tomorrow's competition_.

Comment: Is it because of tomorrow being a possessive noun in here? Shouldn't we put any article before a possessive noun?

Comment: Not if the noun doesn't need an article. _John's dinner is in the oven, the dog's dinner is in its bowl_.

Answer (score -1):

Only Sentences 2 are correct. Sentences 1 are not correct.